# Change ROM of Galaxy Nexus Yakju with CyanogenMod of Maguro

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have a Galaxy Nexus "yakju" model and I want to replace the stock Android with CyanogenMod, but I have found only [this page](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=maguro&type=) which talks about the "maguro". After some research it looks like it will not be different (only where the phone is sold and who update it) and looks like "maguro" is the generic name to mean the Galaxy Nexus phone. My problem is that i'm not really sure if i'm right or not.

Can I flash CyanogenMod without problems? Or could it brick my phone?

Comment: To be confirmed by a Nexus user, but AFAIK it is as you guessed already: I'm sure "Maguro" is the codename for the device. What I'm not 100% sure about (but only 99%) is that YAKJU refers to the *version* of the currently installed firmware. So all together, I'm 99.5% sure you're safe to use those images. What never hurts is making a full backup first (before flashing the new ROM), best a Nandroid backup (from recovery) so if things go wrong you can go back to your current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy Nexus is something of an unusual beast. Because of some regional differences in the factory images (notably, the presence of Google Wallet on the US image) Google distributes multiple *firmwares* for one model of *hardware*.

When determining if CM is supported on your device, you want to ensure the *phone model* is correct. In the case of the GSM Galaxy Nexus, this is "maguro". You can flash a maguro image and it will work correctly. There is no "yakju" or "takju" when referring to CyanogenMod because they build for the device hardware: maguro.

In total, there are three hardware variants of the Galaxy Nexus, but **five** firmwares. They are:

- maguro: The GSM/HSPA+ GNex. This shipped with **one of** the following images:

  - takju: Devices sold via Google in the US. This firmware contains Google Wallet pre-installed.
  - yakju: Devices sold via Google internationally. This does **not** contain Google Wallet.
  - yakjuxw: Devices sold via Samsung.
  - All of these are interchangeable. Any maguro model can run any of these firmwares. The firmware you have determines where updates come from (Google or Samsung), so it was common for people to install takju or yakju firmware on devices that originally came with yakjuxw, in order to get updates faster (i.e. from Google).
- toro: A separate model, made for Verizon. It uses the "mysid" factory image.
- toroplus: A separate model, made for Sprint. It uses the "mysidspr" factory image.

You can find all of these factory images (except yakjuxw) on on [Google's site](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).